# What is the shortest valid and available numerical domain name?

Tags: domains, url, domain-registration

**559.com is unavailable:**

[image]
**10019976.com is available:**

[image]

But how can I figure out the lowest number available as a ".com" domain name?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.namecatch.com/) site for expiring domains. Click on "NNN", "NNNN", and "NNNNN" for numerical domains with corresponding lengths. There are similar options for short letter-based domains.

Answer (score 3):

You could find out programatically using a domain search API, such as [Dynadot's API](http://www.dynadot.com/domain/api.html), which lets you search for available domains in blocks of 100.

But actually posting the shortest available numerical domain here might only ensure that it wasn't the shortest available domain for much longer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the shortest **valid** name, because availability shouldn't be your concern since almost all of short names are already taken!

FYI, 559.com is valid and available through [GoDaddy auctions](https://auctions.godaddy.com/).

The shortest valid numerical domain name that I could find by searching on [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com/) is three digit names, such as 123.com or 111.com, but as you can guess, they're all already taken.

I'm not sure why, but it seems [two letter/digit domains are not available](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29736/how-do-i-register-two-letter-domain-names-for-url-shortening) by many registrars including GoDaddy.